# shiny with rNVD3 work well in rstutio but only show half of the chart in chrome

Tags: r, shiny, nvd3.js, rcharts

I am using rNVD3 in shiny to make charts, it works well in rstudio but it gives an error message:

> ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer

I don't know what's wrong with is

but when I open this app in Chrome or Firefox the charts only show top half (I don't have enough reputation to post images, sorry)

The code is :

```
#ui.r
require(rNVD3)
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("rNVD3: Interactive Charts from R using NVD3.js"),

    sidebarPanel(
       selectInput(inputId = "gender",
            label = "Choose Gender",
            choices = c("Male", "Female"),
            selected = "Male"),
       selectInput(inputId = "type",
            label = "Choose Chart Type",
            choices = c("multiBarChart", "multiBarHorizontalChart"),
            selected = "multiBarChart"),
       checkboxInput(inputId = "stack",
              label = strong("Stack Bars?"),
              value = FALSE)
  ),
 mainPanel(
    showOutput("myChart")
   )
  ))

#server.r
require(rNVD3)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
      output$myChart <- renderChart({
        hair_eye = as.data.frame(HairEyeColor)
        p6 <- nvd3Plot(Freq ~ Hair | Eye, data = subset(hair_eye, Sex == input$gender), 
               type = input$type, id = 'myChart')
    p6$chart(color = c('brown', 'blue', '#594c26', 'green'), stacked = input$stack)
    return(p6)
  })
})
```